# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have updated my php version from php 5.0 to 5.3 and it started showing me this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in
```

I need your help guyz please suggest me what to do.

I have also uncomment `extension=mysql.so` in my php ini file in

```
php.ini
```

I am using Linux

Comment: What does your `phpinfo()` return? Does it include info about MySQL? Server restarted?

Comment: my PHP says  `'--without-mysql'` i have restarted my server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Recommendation**

I would recommend you use `mysqli` ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php ) which is an improved version of `mysql`

**Quick Fix**

Full Details of all possible reason available at

http://www.somacon.com/p109.php

Let me know if you need more assitance

**Last Resort**

Re install PHP53

Remove the 5.1.x PHP Packages:

```
 yum remove php php-*
```

Remove the 5.3.x PHP Packages:

```
 yum remove php php53-*
```

Install PHP5.3

```
yum install php53-cli
yum install php53-common
yum install php53-devel (If you need development support)
yum install php53-gd
yum install php53-mbstring
yum install php53-mysql
yum install php53-soap
yum install php53-xml
yum install php53-xmlrpc
yum install php53-bcmath
yum install php53-snmp
```

Restart Apache

```
Service httpd restart
```

yum search

Comment: I am using centos its about redhat and i have check all steps given on _somacon_ but didn't got sucess :(

Comment: Ok  .. i'll update my answer for another option

Comment: yep, might be necessary and quite important to restart the server as you say

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears because the MySQL module is not active into your PHP installation or because the MySQL module was not compiled with permanent connections support.

In the first case you should check that the `php_mysql` module is enabled into the `php.ini` file and if not, uncomment the line which enable this module. If you are running your PHP on Linux you have to compile this module first. (`--with-mysql=shared`)

Comment: What is the complete command to compile mysql shared.

Answer (score 0):

try to uncomment this lines and restart your server

```
extension = php_pdo.dll
extension = php_mysql.dll
extension = php_mysqli.dll
extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am using linux not windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please Enable 2 extensions in your `php.ini`

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and please check `libmySQL.dll` in your php directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am using linux not windows.

Comment: same for linux too dude

Comment: linux also have directories

Comment: i didn't find any dll file in my server which you are saying..

Comment: oh Sorry i forgot 1 thing dll r not in linux :D                                                                          please go to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php