# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php.ini, database-performance, database-connection

I'm Having same Problem.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in

I gone through [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in](https://serverfault.com/questions/379430/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-pconnect-in). i have same problem. but noothing works for me.

server details:

1. php version 5.3.
2. Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64

Comment: "noothing works for me" probably means you did soothing wrong. You shouldn't really be using that extension at all these days btw.

Comment: PHP 5.3 has hit end of life cycle http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: What would be the possible solution..?

Comment: yum search php-mysql showing only one module. php-mysql.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

You have to install PHP extensions, not only the pure PHP engine. There are two mysql-related extensions - `php5-mysql` and `php5-mysqli`. You have to install both of them.

Comment: No package php5-mysql available. 

No package php5-mysqli available.
I cant able to install.

Comment: yum search php-mysql showing only one module. php-mysql.x86_64.